# Adding to a vector2 in C#? How so?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, vector, xna, flixel

I'm doing a bit of trial and error with Flash/AS3 and Flixel to make a car move to various waypoints on its own. Anyway I have found some code by Microsoft for XNA/C# and am trying to convert it but am stuck on two bits to do with vectors...

```
location = location + (Direction *
                    MoveSpeed * elapsedTime);
```

"location" is a Vector2.

Similarly:

```
tank.Location + (orth * turningRadius)
```

".Location" and "orth" are also both Vector2's.

Can anybody tell me what this is actually doing?

I don't understand how you can add or multiply a single number to a Vector2 but maybe I am missing something obvious!!

Cheers

Chris

Comment: [Scalar multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is doing some nice things for you.  In effect what the code is doing is this:

```
location.X += (orth.X * turningRadius);
location.Y += (orth.Y * turningRadius);
```

A quick and simple vector math intro: http://johnnygizmo.blogspot.com/2008/10/xna-sidebar-intro-to-vector-math.html